# How to store list or key/value pair in Redis cache

Tags: asp.net, session, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I am deploying my projects in Azure since this will be deploy in multiple hosts, I want to change the values present in Session to Redis Cache. For storing single values its quite easy. But i'm not sure how to store a list or table having 5000 values. Please suggest me the best way. Thanks

---

I am using ASP.net application for storing list values in Redis cache. For storing Strings I am using below step.

```
 IDatabase rediscache = connection.GetDatabase();
 rediscache.StringSet(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value.ToString()));
```

In the same way I need to store a list in rediscache. I am using StackExchange.Redis for storing in Azure. Which can be found at:
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis

Comment: What is the exact thing you're asking about - how to cache a list of 5000 items, or how to generate 5000 keys, or is it a performance question, i.e. how to quickly put 5000 items in redis?

Comment: Are yoou using ASP.Net redis session state provider? In what language are you application wrote?